# application exited right after I clicked the button

Tags: android

Hi I'm working on how put register information into DB. When I click the 'Register now" button in login page, the app shut down. What should I do for this problem?

Login.java code

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    EditText ET_NAME,ET_PASS;
    String login_name,login_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_main);
        ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        ET_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
    }
    public void userReg(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
    }
    public void userLogin(View view)
    {
        login_name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        login_pass = ET_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method = "login";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,login_name,login_pass);
    }
}
```

Register.java

```
public class Register extends Activity {
    EditText ET_NAME,ET_USER_NAME,ET_USER_PASS;
    String name,user_name,user_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);
        ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        ET_USER_NAME= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
        ET_USER_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);
    }
    public void userReg(View view)
    {
        name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_name = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_pass =ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method = "register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
        finish();

    }
```

And the log.

```
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Android\1113GMDemo1\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo.Login" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1427)
I/MultiDex: VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
I/MultiDex: install
I/MultiDex: MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.example.jina.a1105gmdemo-19.apk, false)
I/MultiDex: loading existing secondary dex files
I/MultiDex: load found 1 secondary dex files
I/MultiDex: install done
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

when I debugged picking other points, I got log like this.

```
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
              Build Date: 03/21/14 Fri
              Local Branch: AU200+patches_03212014
              Remote Branch: 
              Local Patches: 
              Reconstruct Branch: 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/OpenGLRenderer: GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502
E/OpenGLRenderer:   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

+
This is background code

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
     //   alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
     //   alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information");
     //   alertDialog.setMessage("Login success");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://35.160.135.119/webapp/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://35.160.135.119/webapp/login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie"; // stackoverflow

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                java.net.CookieManager msCookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
                Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = httpURLConnection.getHeaderFields();
                List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);

                if ( cookiesHeader != null) {
                    for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
                        msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                    }
                }
                if (msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
                    // While joining the Cookies, use ',' or ';' as needed. Most of the servers are using ';'
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
                            TextUtils.join(";",  msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
                }

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");


                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (method.equals("login")) {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login_pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove finish() in this method userReg(View view).Actually you are finishing the activity by calling finish().

```
 public void userReg(View view)
 {
    name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_name = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_pass =ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
    String method = "register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
   //finish(); remove it

}
```

Comment: Oh, I did it, but not working.. and in Register activity, it has to finish after editing register information.

Comment: uncomment this line   alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();  in  onPreExecute()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you. But it is possible that you get a NullPointerException in `onPostExecute` method because parameter `result` which is returned by `doInBackground` can be null. Flip the `equals` expression and try again.

Comment: thanks! it works on moving main activity from login activity. Now I have to find out why I can't insert the register data into the mysql..

Comment: Good luck with that :)